# Insert multiple list in database using python django

Tags: python, django, database

Im confused on how can I insert multiple list bycolumn using a loop, let say the output what I want in database is something like this

```
name         percentage       is_fixed_amount

PWD           20                   0
Senior        20                   0
OPD            6                   0
Corporators   20                   0
Special                            1
```

**What I've tried** but it's insert multiple data and it didn't reflect the actual data in database, Can somebody knows the solution? I appreciate any reply.

```
discount = ['PWD','Senior Citizen','OPD','Corporators','Special']
discount_percentage = ['20','20','6','20','']
fixed_amount = [False,False,False,False,True] 


for dis in discount:
    for per in discount_percentage:
        for fix in fixed_amount:
            discount_val = Discounts(name=dis,percentage = per,is_fixed_amount =fix)
            discount_val.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using nested loops to insert values into the database which iterates through the combination of each item 3 lists `discount`, `discount_percentage`, `fixed_amount`. You should try iterating using 1 for loop and access each item in the list by its index

```
discount = ['PWD','Senior Citizen','OPD','Corporators','Special']
discount_percentage = ['20','20','6','20','']
fixed_amount = [False,False,False,False,True] 


for i in range(len(discount)):
    discount_val = Discounts(name=discount[i],percentage = discount_percentage[i],is_fixed_amount =fixed_amount[i])
    discount_val.save()
```